# Do not allow incoming call Lync Api or disabling sounds for incoming call

Tags: c#, lync

I have developed a windows application using Lync api. My client want to disable incoming calls to this application. So i have added some thing like this. I am able to cut the call but there are few rings before im able to do that

```
private void ClientInitialized(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            try
            {
                //registers for conversation related events
                //these events will occur when new conversations are created (incoming/outgoing) and removed
                client.ConversationManager.ConversationAdded += ConversationManager_ConversationAdded;
                client.ConversationManager.ConversationRemoved += ConversationManager_ConversationRemoved;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Problem in adding/removing conversation", "Bella IVIS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

void ConversationManager_ConversationAdded(object sender, ConversationManagerEventArgs e)
        {
     try
     {    
     var _client = client;
     if (e.Conversation.State == ConversationState.Active)
     {
     for (int intLoop = 0; intLoop < _client.ConversationManager.Conversations.Count; intLoop++)
     {
         _client.ConversationManager.Conversations[intLoop].End();
     }
     _client = null;
      return;
     }
    }
  }
```

Comment: ConversationAdded is after a conversation has been added. You want to look at before a conversation is added to determine to block/mute it entirely before it even gets to the point of being added

Comment: is there any event name to look for

Comment: Is this specific to this one client (endpoint) or to the user? If it's for the user you could switch off the audiovideo capability for the user on the server side. Old article which might still be relevant: http://jackiechen.org/2012/02/13/disable-audiovideo-features-in-lync-client/

Comment: Thanks for the article.Currently i am getting ring before hitting the debugger  at ConversationManager_ConversationAdded event. So I am not aware of the event in which i have to block the call and after that i should be able to modify the key again. Do you have any idea on that

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is a way to capture conversation before `Conversation_Added` event. However, if the Lync status is not of any relevance to you then you change the Lync Status to "Do not disturb". This way you would never get any incoming request (unless the user Lync setting allow to do so)

```
var newInformation =new Dictionary<PublishableContactInformationType, object>();
        newInformation.Add(PublishableContactInformationType.Availability, ContactAvailability.DoNotDisturb);

try
{
     this.lyncClient.Self.BeginPublishContactInformation(newInformation,(result) => this.lyncClient.Self.EndPublishContactInformation(result) , null);
}  catch {}
```